# Define function to create a RegularPolygon of a particular color and number of sides

Tags: polygons

Define a function coloredPolygon to create a RegularPolygon of a particular color and number of sides. Use OptionsPattern in the definition to accept two options: color and sides. The first option will be used to specify the color of the polygon and the second option sides will be used to specify the number of sides. Use Options to set the default values for the two options. Set the default color to be Orange and default number of sides to be 3.

Here is my tentative code (with faults):

```
coloredPolygon := RegularPolygon [color, sides];
Options [coloredPolygon] {color ->Orange, sides->3}
coloredPolygon[]
```

Getting this error message:

[image]

Comment: You could  do: `rp[n_ : 3, col_ : Red] := 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{col, Thick}], FaceForm[None], RegularPolygon[n]}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[coloredPolygon]

Options[coloredPolygon] = {color -> Orange, sides -> 3};

coloredPolygon[opts:OptionsPattern[]] :=
  {OptionValue[color], RegularPolygon[OptionValue[sides]]};

coloredPolygon[]
```

[image]

```
coloredPolygon[sides -> 5]
```

[image]

```
Graphics @ coloredPolygon[sides -> 7, color -> Red]
```

[image]

**Note:** You can use both `s` and `"s"` to refer to option `s`; that is, `sides -> something` and `"sides" -> something` (similarly, both `color -> somecolor` and `"color" -> somecolor`) work:

```
coloredPolygon[sides -> 7, color -> Red]
```

[image]

```
coloredPolygon["color" -> Red, "sides" -> 7]
```

[image]

Comment: @kgir Is it not strange that Options command with coloredPolygon used before defining the function coloredPolygon in the next step.

Comment: @SplendidDigitalSolutions, `Options[foo] =...` can be before or after `foo` is defined.

Comment: @kgir This feature must be because unlike old programming languages like BASIC, this is not a procedural programming in which the second step relies on the first step and ordering is important.

Comment: @SplendidDigitalSolutions, you might find the info in [Option Value >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionValue.html) useful.

Comment: @SplendidDigitalSolutions You have asked several questions that are quizzes or exercises from Wolfram-U courses. This is not the forum for asking those questions. They should be asked on the Wolfram Community site post corresponding to the course. The point of a quiz or exercise is for you to solve it, not ask someone else to solve it for you.